# How to change current time of a paused html5 video and start playing from that position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a html 5 video on a page like this:

```
<video preload="none" id="movie" poster="http://my_poster_url.com/sourcefile.jpeg" controls>
     <source id="mp4" type="video/mp4" src="http://my_mp4.com/sourcefile.mp4"></source>
     <source id="webm" type="video/webm" src="http://my_webm.com/sourcefile.webm"></source>
</video>
```

Below that video I have a navigation where you can skip to different times in the video. It works perfectly when the video is playing, but when paused following error occurs:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not,
>   or is no longer, usable

Here the function:

```
$('#my_video_navigation a').click(function () {
    var start_in_seconds=...//a variable that gets the time from a json based on the navigation index
    $("#movie").get(0).currentTime = start_in_seconds;
    $("#movie").get(0).play();
}
```

I added an if/else statement wether the video is paused or not:

```
if ($('#movie').get(0).paused) {
    $("#movie").get(0).play(); 
}
```

and then tried to set the current time like above and even with a set timeout function so that it will wait till the video loaded and is playing but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong or what did I forget?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `currentTime` field of the media element, as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) in the API doc. There is also an example code here, at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

For reference, the sample  code there:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('mediaElementID');
mediaElement.seekable.start();  // Returns the starting time (in seconds)
mediaElement.seekable.end();    // Returns the ending time (in seconds)
mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds
mediaElement.played.end();      // Returns the number of seconds the browser has played
```

where the `mediaElementID` is the id of the `audio` or `video` tag.

Edit: It seems I've misread your question. I will take a further look.

Comment: Thx. But you are right. You misread the question ;) I know the duration of the video and how to change the current time when playing. The problem is that it won't work when the video is paused.